# Trying to get property 'role' of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 levels of authenticating users.

In the first level, I have only username and password and in the second level, I have access roles of the users.

The problem with this is,

There are chances where a user whose data is present in the first table but not in second table i.e,the access table tries to login.

I don't have copy of all the users from the first table in the second table.

Is there any possible way I could check if the user exists in the second table in a query?

For now my query is

```
$roleQuery= " SELECT role FROM accesscredentials WHERE jid=".$_POST['username'];       
$roleArray=mysqli_query($con,$roleQuery);
$roleVal = mysqli_fetch_object($roleArray);
$role=$roleVal->role;
```

when users try to login, Since their name is not in the second table, I'm getting an error saying 
" Trying to get property 'role' of non-object

Could you help me with this?
Thank you :)
cheers

Comment: Have you try to _var_dump($roleVal)_ ?

Comment: You don't check that the query actually returned something. What if there are 0 rows returned?

Comment: Your query is also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: if `$_POST['username']` is a STRING then your query is invalid as there are no quotes around that value

Comment: @Qirel,exactly.Thats my problem.I'm trying to access something thats not in the table. I need something that will possibly tell the user does not exist.Only if the user exists I need it to return some value.

Comment: @RamRaider ,Hi,this query works for the one's where user exists in the table.Only when there is no such user I have an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$roleQuery= "SELECT role FROM accesscredentials WHERE jid=".$_POST['username'];

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$roleQuery))
  {
  while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
       echo $obj->role;
    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [mysqli_fetch_object()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) says:

> Returns an object with string properties that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.

So you can check this:

```
if (is_null($roleVal)) {
    $role = "not set.";
}
else {
    $role = $roleVal->role;
}
```

Do protect your queries against SQL attacks, use [prepared statements](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/prepared-statements).

The alternative suggested by Qirel would look like this:

```
if ($roleArray->num_rows > 0) {
    $roleVal = mysqli_fetch_object($roleArray);
    $role=$roleVal->role;
}
else {
    $role = "not set.";
}
```

Either one will do the job. But to make it complete with a prepared statement you would have to do:

```
// sanatize input before anything else
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
// perform prepared query
$roleQuery = "SELECT role FROM accesscredentials WHERE jid=?";       
$roleStatement = $con->prepare($roleQuery);
$roleStatement->bind_param("s", $username);
$roleStatement->bind_result($role);
$roleStatement->execute();
// fill role with something when not found
if (!$roleStatement->fetch()) {
    $role = "not set.";
}
// now you can use $role
```

Comment: Or check `$roleArray->num_rows` is also a way to go :-)

Comment: @Qirel: Sure, that's a good altenative, and you can do that before getting the object.

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues and one vulerability. The vulnerability can be fixed by using a prepared statement, but that also fixes your first issue - that the string-value `$_POST['username']` must be quoted in the query.

Finally, you must check if there are any rows to fetch before actually being able to use those values.

```
$roleQuery= " SELECT role FROM accesscredentials WHERE jid=?";       
$stmt = $con->prepare($roleQuery);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bind_result($role);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "Role was ".$role;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and suggestion :) I used prepare statement and this works amazingly :)

Comment: Your original code does *not* use a prepared statement - this answer and RamRaider's does - you should use one of these answers, if you aren't already ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a great fan of `try/catch` blocks in certain situations and this seems to me like one such use-case scenario. By using a `prepared statement` you eliminate ( virtually ) the possibility of SQL injection attacks and negate the possible error of not quoting strings in the sql ( the value presumably was numeric )

Using the try/catch means you can raise your own useful debugging messages to assist debug the logic without resorting to using `mysqli_error()` etc which reveals too much in many cases.

Hopefully this might be of use to you

```
try{
    $sql='select `role` from `accesscredentials` where `jid`=?';
    $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){
        $username=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        if( $username ){

            $stmt->bind_param('s',$username );
            $status=$stmt->execute();

            if( $status && $stmt->num_rows==1 ){

                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result( $role );
                $stmt->fetch();
                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();

                /* $role is available as a variable */
                echo $role;

            } else {
                throw new Exception( $stmt->num_rows==0 ? 'Query failed or there are no records' : 'Error' );
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No valid username');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Failed to prepare "SELECT" query');
    }
}catch( Exception $e ){
    exit( $e->getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: ha ha.Try catch works like a charm :)

Comment: You should make it a distinct exception instead of using a root Exception class. There could be other exceptions that shouldn't be echoed to the user. And being a fan is generally a bad service, as some exceptions shouldn't be added at all, like 'Failed to prepare "SELECT" query' one. Being a reasonable user is better.